# android - manually calling onSaveInstanceState not working

Tags: android

I have a android fragment hosted in an activity. The activity is not overriding any onsaveInstanceState or onRestoreInstanceState methods. in my fragment i put the following code:

```
  @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelable("mymodel", myModel);
        onSaveInstanceState(b);
    }
```

when user hits the back button i see this being called (i know its not guaranteed for ondestroy to be called, thats not my point).  so i put a break point and indeed this code gets called.  Then i return to the activity and it opens the fragment but the savedInstanceState is null in oncreate and in onViewCreated.  What am i doing wrong ? i thought i could call this manually to save state ?

Comment: Please check this post for saving instance state
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot call `onSaveInstanceState` manually. The framework does that for you. Calling that will only update your bundle, not the framework bundle. The proper way is to override it and save your data.

Comment: yes i see what you mean. instead what i have done is converted the model to json string and serialized it to shared prefs. when i want to restore it i deserialize it from sharedprefs.

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `onSaveInstanceState` manually, it is Android Framework's job to do that whenever it is necessary.

If you want to save information and retrieve it later, just override `onSaveInstanceState` and put your info in the bundle.